# Laravel minimum length validation for numbers not working

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5.5

Laravel minimum length validation for numbers not working, please find the following expressions

```
  'country_code' => 'regex:/^.{2,4}$/',
  'country_code' => 'bail|required|numeric',
```

i need to restrict 1 digit nubers including zero
ex: (01,+1,00,99,999,......) are valid 
(0,+,1,......) are invalid

Comment: i think remove `bail` validation and add `min:1`

Comment: min:1 won't count zero as a digit. means if I input 01 then validation will throw an error. in my case, I need to allow such numbers

Comment: 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{2,4}$/' also not working

Comment: try use `regex:^\+[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3,14}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the maximum number you want to match is 999, you might use an  [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either a plus followed by matching 1-3 digits or match 2-3 digits.

`^(?:\+\d{1,3}|\d{2,3})$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3MSxll/1)

Comment: it's working
'country_code' => ['bail','required','numeric','regex:/^(?:\+\d{1,4}|\d{2,4})$/']

Comment: @manu I see, there can be 4 digits max instead of 3. Glad it works!

Answer (score 0):

to allow `01` in your case try

```
^(?:[0-9][0-9]{1,3}|[0-9])$
```

[see](https://regex101.com/r/xjJVxI/2)